# WordPress - page not found with inštrukcije

Tags: wordpress, idn

I have a domain named inštrukcije, which includes š character.

I used IDN translator to translate it to: xn--intrukcije-19b.si

I installed new WordPress on this domain at: http://xn--intrukcije-19b.si/

When I try to navigate the page, I get:

> The requested URL /pages/ was not found on this server.

I think maybe its a problem with domain - I have it with Balkan characters inštrukcije so I changed in MySQL, in table wp_options entry siteurl from [http://inštrukcije.si](http://xn--intrukcije-19b.si) to http://xn--intrukcije-19b.si (which I use for domain...)

but the page is still not working...

What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

What i had to do:

1. go to setting permalink
2. change from post name to default
3. change again from default to postname

and now is working...